# pipe command output to convert?

Tags: zsh, pipe, imagemagick

I have a folder containing files of the format file(0).jpg to file(100).jpg

I can't directly use convert to generate a pdf here because the order ends up being 0,1,100,2,20,21,...

`echo *.jpg(n)` gives the correct order of files.

how do I pipe this into convert?

I have tried `echo *.jpg(n) | convert - out.pdf`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the command that you'd like to execute is

```
convert 'file(0).jpg' 'file(1).jpg' ...etc... 'file(100).jpg' out.pdf
```

then either use your glob,

```
convert ./*.jpg(n) out.pdf
```

or to only include files in 0..100 range that match that pattern:

```
convert 'file('<0-100>').jpg'(n) out.pdf
```

or you could use a brace expansion:

```
convert 'file('{0..100}').jpg' out.pdf
```

Though note that it's not *globbing*, the strings `file(0).jpg` through to `file(100).jpg` will be passed to convert regardless of whether these are names of  existing files or not. Contrary to the previous one, it would also miss files named `file(012).jpg` for instance.

Answer (score 5):

If you have many files which will cause you to run into the command line limit of the OS, you should use `convert`'s `@` "filename reference" feature:

```
generate the list of files ... | convert @- out.pdf
```

On a shell which doesn't support `*.jpg(n)` globs like `zsh` does, you can generate the list of files in the right order with:

```
echo 'file('?').jpg' 'file('??').jpg' 'file('???').jpg' | convert @- out.pdf
```

Or with a shell which support brace expansion:

```
echo 'file('{?,??,???}').jpg' | convert @- out.pdf
```

Unlike `{1..100}` this will only match files that exist. Since `echo` is a built-in in most shells, it's not subject to the command line limit of the OS, so this kind of construct may turn into a useful UUoE.